# Does Space Take Up a Character Count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 columns:

`Name` `nvarchar 100`

`FirstName` `nvarchar 50`

`LastName` `nvarchar 50`

Can `Name` take in `FirstName + ' ' + LastName` if both are maxed out (50 characters)?

Comment: The result will be 101 characters.

Comment: Yes, a space counts as a character. It is a character (ASCII char 32 (20 hex).) Why would you want to have three columns at all? That's a clear (and unnecessary) duplication of data.

Comment: My apologies. They are not the exact columns that I am facing. I used a wrong example in my question.

Comment: The exact columns don't matter. It's simply not necessary to store the value of two columns concatenated together. It's a meaningless repetition of data that causes nothing but problems and uses unnecessary space in the DB. There is never an acceptable exuse to store COLUMN1 + COLUMN2 in COLUMN3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can Name take in FirstName + ' ' + LastName if both are maxed out (50 characters)?

No.

If FirstName and LastName actually use the entire 50 char column width, there's no room for the space, and the new string containing the space won't fit.

OTOH, there's really no reason to store first and last then another column containing them both glued together. This could easily be done in the SQL query as needed with `SELECT Firstname + ' ' + LastName as [Name] FROM TableName`

In fact, it's better to not store first + space + last because once you get two copies of any chunk of data, eventually one is going to be wrong. Someone will have a name change and the "Name" field won't get updated.